# Working on the same git with two different pc's. Two different postgresql settings in the settings.py file

Tags: django, git, postgresql

I'm very new to databases and I'm trying to find out what the best practise for what I'm trying to achieve.

I have the one repository which is a Django backend with a postgresql database attached. I'm working with this on my main pc but recently I've had to work on my laptop. My laptop has another postgresql database running on 5432, so I've had to change some of that info to be on port 54324. These changes I don't want pushed to the repository, but I would still like to track the settings.py file in the repository. So far I've just created a branch for each pc to maintain the separate settings, but I'm sure this is not a great way to do it. I've heard about setting up environment files, but I'm unsure about if this is the 'right way' to do it either.

I'm a little confused with the best way I can do this, hopefully I'm making sense. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides [eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60543205/1256452), consider having a committed `config.defaults.py` file that set *default* configuration values that may be *overridden* by a per-site `config.local.py` file.  If the default configuration works for you, you don't need to create the per-site config.  If not, create the per-site config.  Never commit (and do `.gitignore`) the per-site config.

The names of the configuration files might be located outside the repository proper, but the overall idea still applies.  The distributed (and committed) configuration file is a *sample* and/or *default* and actual site settings are kept in some other file that is never committed.

If you already have a single `config.py` or `settings.py`, you can establish this configuration pattern by *adding* `site.py` (use whatever name you want for this per-site setting file) as an ignored file.  Read the new file, if it exists, such that the site settings override the default settings from the existing tracked file, and you're good to go.

Comment: Ok great I think this is starting to make a little more sense. So if I'm looking at this from a next step kind of view, I should:

- create a site.py file
- create a conditional if the file exists, change the db information, else use defaults

Ok, I'm going to mess around with this a bit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is normally solved with a properties file that is *ignored*. What you keep is a sample file (that has a different name) and that you do track and change accordingly on git. Your python scripts read the properties file and everybody should be happy.

Comment: OK, I think I'm following you. So I would create a properties file with the environment specific settings for the database. How would I reference this file in the settings.py file? Maybe and if statement? Sorry, I'm very new to this stuff.

`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'newPassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '54324',
    }
}`